# Listbox events in HTML

Tags: html, events, listbox

I want to call 'onclick' event on listbox. There is 'onchange' event which is called whenever the displayed options changes but I want to call a function when the list box is selected or the displayed option is selected again. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think by using HTML listbox you cant find Click event. It is Having only change event.
[Refer This](http://www.functionx.com/html/lesson14.htm) 
But You can Do it by some other way Using JavaScript. I found one interesting link [Refer This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/List_Box.aspx)
good Luck.

Comment: The first link is dead.